# useEffect hook not setting state object properly

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect

Ok I literally cannot figure out why this is happening. I am doing this same thing on different components and sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I use the useEffect hook to get an object from my firebase storage. I get the object properly as shown in my console but I literally cannot access any nested values.

Code:

```
const ReviewComponent = (props) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
  const [campaigns, setCampaigns] = useState([])
  const [currentCampaign, setCurrentCampaign] = useState([])

//First useEffect hook used for something else in the code
  const tempDoc = []
      useEffect(() => {
        var docRef = db.collection("campaigns");
        docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
          querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            tempDoc.push({ id: doc.id, ...doc.data() })
              // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
              setCampaigns(tempDoc)
          });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
          console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
      });
      },[]);


//Second use effect hook (THIS IS THE ONE CAUSING ISSUES)
      useEffect(() => {
        const docRef = db.collection("campaigns").doc(slug);
    
        docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
            if (doc.exists) {
                console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
                setCurrentCampaign(doc.data()) 
            } else {
                // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
                console.log("No such document!");
            }
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Error getting document:", error);
      });
    },[]);


  const handleOpen = () => {
    setOpen(true)
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  if(currentCampaign[0]) { // Or if(campaign[0])

    console.log(currentCampaign) //this never gets logged 
  }

  return(
    <Typography>
    {currentCampaign.reviews[0].text} // TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined, if I do currentCampaign.reviews -> TypeError: Cannot read property 'reviews' of undefined
   </Typography>
)
```

[image: Text]

As you can the above picture shows the object logged from within the useEffect hook. I try logging it by checking is currentCampaign[0] exists. It never exists. If I do currentCampaign.body or any other top level elements, it works fine in my return statement. If I do anything nested such as currentCampaign.images[0].url -> ERROR :

I can get access to all the top level properties such as body, campaignPolicy etc. but if I do

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of undefined

If I do campaign.startDate.seconds i get same error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of undefined

Answer (score 1):

```
if(currentCampaign[0]) { // Or if(campaign[0])
    console.log(currentCampaign) //this never gets logged 
}
```

You can't request the state value at the root level of `ReviewComponent` component, which means the same level of the state definition. This is called once initially when the component is rendered, so currentCampaign is always empty.

You should use this inside the `useEffect` with adding a state dependency.

```
useEffect(() => {
  if(currentCampaign[0]) {
    console.log(currentCampaign)
  }
}, [currentCampaign]);
```

---

```
return(
    <Typography>
       {currentCampaign.reviews[0].text}
   </Typography>
```

Regarding this error, currentCampaign is initially empty array, so at the first time of this component rendering, currentCampaign.reviews will be undefined. Thus `currentCampaign.reviews[0].text` will be the error.

You should always check `currentCampaign` if it is undefined or not.

FYI, `currentCampaign` is array in your state definition, so try to correct the syntax to request `currentCampaign` variable.

Comment: If I check if currentCampaign[0] exists in return statement it never displays what I want it to display because currentCampaign is always empty. So how do I even get the values inside the state??

Comment: as long as currentCampaign is updated by `setCurrentCampaign`, component will be re-rendered, so you will see the currentCampaign value.

Comment: you already `setCurrentCampaign` in the second useEffect, so once that call is succeed, currentCampaign will be filled with the value.

Comment: what is the type of `doc.data()`? are you sure it is array?

Comment: I added picture showing exactly what doc.data() returns. currentCampaign in my return statement only lets me access top level elements. If I do currentCampaign.body, it works fine. If I do currentCampaign[0].reviews.title it throws error as shown above.

Comment: that means, currentCampaign is the object, you should update the type.
  const [currentCampaign, setCurrentCampaign] = useState({})